# Android App start with virtual keyboard open

Tags: android

I am writing an app for android phones and after my splash screen it shows an activity which has several spinners and edittext views.

On an android device without a keyboard it shows the virtual keyboard which then blocks the rest of the app and looks unprofessional to me.  I have tried to hide the virtual keyboard in the activity.onCreate method however no avail there.

My next option I tried was setting an onFocus listener to the actual offending edittext view and still no avail.

How can I prevent the virtual keyboard from showing until a user explicitly clicks an edittext view?  Is there a way to give one of the spinner's focus since one of the spinners is before the edittext view in the layout xml?

Answer (score 34):

You can try setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute of your Activity's entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I think setting it to `stateHidden` might do what you want.

Here's the 
[docs from the Android site.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

Oncreate of your activity, set the input type to TYPE_NULL. Then, onTouch, set it to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.

```
    myText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    myText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        myText.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        return true; // consume touch even
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, now my app acts more professional.  I noticed other apps like the yahoo email app work in the same way, nice to have apps look alike to add to feel and functionality.

Comment: I believe this is a nice workaround, but that mportuesisf answer is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several more answers with another experience on this issue in thread [Automatic popping up keyboard on start Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity)