# Automatic popping up keyboard on start Activity

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-edittext

I got a relative simple question. I have an activity with a lot of EditText's in them. When I open the activity it automatically focusses to the first EditText and displays the virtual keyboard.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Comment: When My App is Launch (open) and if edit text view is Available so, keyboard is Automatic (show) enable. How to sole this problem click here https://www.easycomacademy.com/when-my-app-is-launch-open-and-if-edit-text-view-is-available-so-keyboard-is-automatic-show-enable/

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Use this attributes in your layout tag in XML file:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

As reported by other members in comments it doesn't works on `ScrollView` therefore you need to add these attributes to the main child of `ScrollView`.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. I added this to the RelativeLayout tag for my activity.  Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly enough, it didn't work when I added the above to a ScrollView, but it did work for a LinearLayout

Comment: I think you have to put it on topmost layout

Comment: So I guess this works because you are telling the layout itself that it can have focus? Otherwise it assumes that it needs to give focus to the first control on the form? Oddly enough, I was getting the keyboard even if all the controls on my form were disabled. Fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: It doesnt work for my top level scrollview, I suggest to use Mobile Bloke's answer, so far works for me everytime (in android manifest activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize")

Comment: Thank you - like mentioned earlier, this didnt' work on a scrollview, but worked on a linearlayout

Comment: Check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Comment: It's important to note that this solution creates accessibility problems (a view that should not be focusable being marked as having focus) and could have unintended consequences.

Comment: It works for me, thank you.. I put this code on <LinearLayout />

Comment: If you are facing the issue in activities, You can check this link, It'll work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts/60429616#60429616

Answer (score 98):

You can add this to your Android Manifest activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: This works, however if you have an image background and are worried about your soft Keyboard shrinking such image background, use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Answer (score 31):

I have several implementations described here, but now i have added into the `AndroidManifest.xml` for my `Activity` the property:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

#### I think this is the easy way even if you are using `fragments`.

> "**[stateAlwaysHidden](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)**"  The soft keyboard is always hidden when the
>   activity's main window has input focus.

Comment: this worked for me with both a ScrollView and a RelativeLayout.

Comment: It's not that great for fragments, as you are associating the "hidden state" with the activity that will contain all your fragments, meaning that any fragment you want to display in the activity will be affected by the property (not on a "per fragment" basis).

Answer (score 11):

If you have another view on your activity like a `ListView`, you can also do:

```
ListView.requestFocus();
```

in your onResume() to grab focus from the `editText`.

I know this question has been answered but just providing an alternative solution that worked for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your Activity's code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: This did not work for me - the keyboard still popped up when I start my activity.

Comment: You can check this link, It'll work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts/60429616#60429616

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11627976/5217837 This is almost correct:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

}
```

But it should be SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN rather than SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE

Answer (score 3):

I had a simular problem, even when switching tabs the keyboard popped up automatically and stayed up, with Android 3.2.1 on a Tablet. Use the following method:

```
public void setEditTextFocus(EditText searchEditText, boolean isFocused)
{
    searchEditText.setCursorVisible(isFocused);
    searchEditText.setFocusable(isFocused);
    searchEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(isFocused);
    if (isFocused) {
        searchEditText.requestFocus();
    } else {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );
    }
}
```

In the onCreate() and in the onPause() of the activity for each EditText:

**setEditTextFocus(myEditText, false);**

For each EditText an OnTouchListener:

```
    myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new EditText.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            setEditTextFocus(myEditText, true); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

For each `EditText` in the `OnEditorActionListener`:

```
    myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                            .......
            setEditTextFocus(myEditText, false); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And for each `EditText` in the `layout xml`:

```
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" // Or something else
```

There is probably more code optimizing possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
((InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService("input_method")).hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.edittxt.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: using fragment ..this code work to hide keyboard ...when a fragment open avoid the focus on edittext field keyboard ...

Answer (score 2):

I have found this simple solution that worked for me.Set these attributes in your parent layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

And now, when the activity starts this main layout will get focus by default.

Also, we can remove focus from child views at runtime by giving the focus to the main layout again, like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).requestFocus();
```

Hope it will work for you .

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution I am using, is not the best solution but it's working well for me

```
 editComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
 editComment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    editComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                     editComment.requestFocus() ;
                    return false;
                }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html states that when an activity starts and focus is given to a text field, the soft keyboard is not shown (and then goes on to show you how to have the keyboard shown if you want to with some code).

On my Samsung Galaxy S5, this is how my app (with no manifest entry or specific code) works -- no soft keyboard. However on a Lollipop AVD, a soft keyboard is shown -- contravening the doc given above.

If you get this behavior when testing in an AVD, you might want to test on a real device to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This has some good answers at the following post : [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/7550472). The one I regularly use is the following code by [Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/7550472) :

```
<!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="0px"/>

<!-- :nextFocusUp and :nextFocusLeft have been set to the id of this component
to prevent the dummy from receiving focus again -->
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext"     
    android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"/>
```

*NOTE :* The dummy item has to be PLACED RIGHT BEFORE the focusable element.

And I think it should work perfectly even with ScrollView and haven't had any problems with accessibility either for this.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when your EditText automatically gets Focus as when you activity starts.  So one easy and stable way to fix this, is simply to set the initial focus to any other view, such as a Button etc.

You can do this in your layout XML, no code required..

Answer (score 0):

**Accepted answer is not working for me,** that's why give answer working solution, may be it is helpful !

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
edt.requestFocus();    
edt.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
edt.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
```

Now keyboard is open enjoy :)

Comment: The question was how to **prevent** the keyboard from opening.

Answer (score 0):

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your top of the activity XML and make sure the View is above EditText

```
<View 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Add the above line to xml of `EditText` or `TextInputLayout` which has focus and is causing the `softInputKeyboard` to pop up.

This solved the problem for us and now the keyboard doesn't popup

Answer (score 0):

search_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

```
    search_edit_text.requestFocus();
    search_edit_text.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
    search_edit_text.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
```

This works for me guys fragment may have some different syntax . **THIS WORKS FOR ACTIVITY**

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Activity's code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your view has EditText and Listview then Keyboard will open up by default.
To hide keyboard from popping up by default do the following

```
this.listView.requestFocus();
```

Make sure you are requesting focus on listview after getting view for editText.

For e.g.

```
this.listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);
this.editTextSearch = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
this.listView.requestFocus();
```

If you do it, then editText will get focus and keyboard will pop up.

Comment: I did this but they keyboard still pops up and the focus is with the editText.