# Get rid of annoying EditText focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, spinner, focusable

I have a pretty big `ScrollView` that consists of `EditTexts` and `Spinners`. 
I have a huge problem with `EditText` focus that has been driving me nuts for the last 2 days. The issue is:

After editing an `EditText`, press 'back' to close the keyboard (the EditText) still remains focused, so when I scroll down to a Spinner and pick an item, the ScrollView jumps back to the last focused EditText, which is very annoying.

I've looked all over StackOverflow and tried everything. I've tried `clearFocus()` on the EditText after editing, but the focus just jumps to another EditText. I put     `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`  and `android:focusable="true"`on the parent `LinearLayout`, hoping that it would steal the focus. Still doesn't work.
I have tried setting click listeners on spinners, and calling `requestFocus()` when clicking them. Nothing works.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554322/7557205  
------
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395246/7557205

Comment: This only hides the keyboard when the activity starts. Not a solution for my case