# Activity under current Activity is seen when keyboard pops-up

Tags: android, android-activity, android-keypad

From `Activity A` I start `Activity B`. Activity B has an `EditText` in it at the very bottom of the screen. When focusing it, the entire screen gets pushed up (animated) and the keyboard pops-up but for a second while it fades in (alongside the translation animation) `Activity A` can be seen underneath.

How can I make it so this does not happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic popping up keyboard on start Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity)

Comment: Unfortunately (for me) no, it's not a duplicate. The other issue is that the keyboard popups up automatically. My problem is that you can see the activity underneath, so it's not pertaining to the automatic opening of the keyboard.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan what happens if you remove the animation?

Comment: It's the default animation for the keyboard. I intended on removing it, but couldn't find a way of doing so.